# PHP Unable to check login details

Tags: php, class, session, cookies, authentication

I am learning PHP and started using classes. I am trying to make login system but unable to verify username and password from database. When I click login it is not letting me in. I tried to check how far I am going inside a function by echo and `die()`, I am stuck at `_`check_db() in `login_action()`, the `_check_db` is not returning something or there is something wrong in my statement.

My Class adminLoginModel.php :

```
<?php
class adminLogin
{
    private $_host="localhost";
    private $_username="root";
    private $_password="";
    private $_database="sms";
    private $_conn;

    private $_loginusername;
    private $_loginpassword;

    public function __construct()
    {
        session_start();
        if(isset($_POST['loginusername'])) {
            $this->_loginusername = $_POST['loginusername'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['loginpassword'])) {
            $this->_loginpassword = $_POST['loginpassword'];
            //get the username and password
        }
        }
    protected function _dbConnect()
    {
        try {
            $this->_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->_host;dbname=$this->_database", $this->_username, $this->_password);
            return $this->_conn;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

    public function authenticate()
    {
        //first check whether session is set or not
        if(!isset($_SESSION['admin_login']))
        {
            //check the cookie
            if(isset($_COOKIE['loginusername']) && isset($_COOKIE['loginpassword']))
            {
                //cookie found, is it really someone from the
                if($this->_check_db($_COOKIE['loginusername'], $_COOKIE['loginpassword']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['admin_login'] = $_COOKIE['loginusername'];
                    header("location: /views/adminView.php");
                    die();
                }
                else {

                    header("location: /index.php");
                    die();
                }
            }
            else {
                header("location: /index.php");
                die();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check for login in the action file
     */
    public function login_action()

    {
        //insufficient data provided
        if ($this->_loginusername == '' || $this->_loginpassword == '')
        {
            header("location: /index.php");
        }

        //check the database for username
        if ($this->_check_db($this->_loginusername,$this->_loginpassword))
        {
                $_SESSION['admin_login'] = $this->_loginusername;
                 //ready to login
                //check to see if remember, ie if cookie
                if (isset($this->$_POST['rememberlogin'])) {
                    //set the cookies for 1 day, ie, 1*24*60*60 secs
                    //change it to something like 30*24*60*60 to remember user for 30 days
                    setcookie('loginusername', $this->_loginusername, time() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
                    setcookie('loginpassword', $this->_loginpassword, time() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
                } else {
                    //destroy any previously set cookie
                    setcookie('loginusername', '', time() - 1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
                    setcookie('loginpassword', '', time() - 1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
                }

                header("location: /views/adminView.php");
            }
    else
        {
                header("location: /index.php");
            }

            die();
        }

    private function _check_db($passedusername,$passedpassword)
    {
        $this->_dbConnect();

        $checkAdminQuery = $this->_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `admins` WHERE `username` = ?");
        $checkAdminQuery->execute(array($passedusername));
        $row = $checkAdminQuery->fetch();
        if ($row['username'] == $passedusername && $row['password'] == $passedpassword)
        {
            $this->_conn = null; //close the connection
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;

        }
    }}?>
```

And Login form :

```
<div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form role="form" id="loginForm" method="post" action="/controllers/mainController.php">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="loginusername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="loginusername" type="text" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="loginpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="loginpassword" type="password" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label for "rememberlogin">
                            <input name="rememberlogin" id="rememberlogin" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="submit" name="login" onclick="return loginCheck()" >Login</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And in controller a little code :

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    include_once(ROOT.'/models/adminLoginModel.php');
    $admin = new adminLogin();
    $admin->login_action();

}
```

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between function (_dbConnect or _check_db) and adminLogin class? I mean, no. If You learn, do it properly. You can read documentation of Symfony/Laravel/Zend framework about authentication

Comment: Security wise your implementation is not good at all. Never use cookie for authentication for example.

As it was said below: look at modern framework authentication and copy them. You will learn much more.